# How can I make a SwiftUI Text view show two lines regardless of text length?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'd like to create a Text view that shows two lines of content, and either cut off the remaining text if there is too much, or just display one or two empty lines if the text isn't long enough or is even an empty string. Is this currently possible? Could I create my own Text view that could somehow behave this way?

Comment: @dfd Thanks for your input. It sounds like you're a little combative though, and I'm not sure why. First of all, I only asked my question 9 hours ago. I didn't get to the other answer until just now. Second of all, my question is about SwiftUI, not UIKit. If the answer to any "How do I do ___ in SwiftUI" is "use UIKit", then we might as well delete the "SwiftUI" tag on SO. Besides, what if I intend to use my SwiftUI view on Apple Watch? UIKit is not an option on the watch.

Answer (score 7):

For **limiting the lines** to only takes two, Use `.lineLimit(2)` modifier.

For **showing empty space** if it's empty, you may use `.frame()` modifier. But if you need to find exact hight of the two line label and apply it, use a placeholder inside a `ZStack` like this:

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {
    Text("\n ").hidden() // Just a place holder to hold required height to show two lines
    Text("Text").lineLimit(2)
}
```

**UPDATE duo to comments**

Remember, there are other issues related to other parts of the SwiftUI, For example if you need to use it inside a `StackView`, you must specify the `layoutPriority` since it's not required by default.

```
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                Text("\n ").lineLimit(2)
                Text("Text").lineLimit(2)
            }.layoutPriority(1000)
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
                Text("Next")
            }
        }
    }
```

And if you see SwiftUI likes to trim extra spaces, you can use hidden characters in the placeholder to make it retain. Use this if needed:

```
(Text("‌‌‎‌‌‎ ")+Text("\n")+Text("‌‌‎ ")).lineLimit(2)
```

Note that the first and last `Text` contains an **special hidden character**.

And **yes**, you can append Texts together.

Comment: Interesting approach. Unfortunately for me it seems to be a little unstable when I try this. When I run this, I see two lines, but the second line disappears on its own after a second. Maybe a SwiftUI bug?

Comment: Maybe, or maybe because of that ‘hidden’ modifier. Get rid of it and test again @Eugene

Comment: Removing .hidden() results in more or less the same thing. Now the second line stays longer, but still disappears after I navigate to a different view then come back.